# Template error , while creating a simple website using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web.py

I was creating a simple website using web.py framework . But when i ran the website it gave template error.

My html file code

```
def with (greeting)
<html>
<head>
<title> "This is a web project"</title>
<body>
<H1>"Yoyo honey singh"</H1>
<H6>greeting<H6>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

My python file code

```
import web

urls = ("/","Index")

app = web.application(urls,globals())

render = web.template.render("\templates")

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        greeting = "HELLO WORLD"
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I placed the index.html file in the template folder and the python script in the bin folder. The directory structure is like

D:\WEBSITE
WEBSITE
    NAME
        **init**.py
    bin
        app.py
    tests
        **init**.py
    docs
    templates

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#templating) you should put a `$` before each python statement in the template. Therefore the first file becames:

```
$def with (greeting)
<html>
<head>
<title> "This is a web project"</title>
<body>
<H1>"Yoyo honey singh"</H1>
<H6>$greeting<H6>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```